# Passing Variable from javascript(Ajax) to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have got a script for file uploading with progress bar . I have done some modifications to do some check and everything working perfectly. Just have a little problem about passing a variable from the javascript(ajax) file to the php file

here is my code:

```
var handleUpload = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var folder = 7;
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');

    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('ajax', true);
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; ++i){
        data.append('file[]', fileInput.files[i]);
    }   

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
        if(event.lengthComputable){
            var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
            var progress = document.getElementById('upload_progress');

            while (progress.hasChildNodes()){
                progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
            }
            progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(percent * 100) +' %'));
            document.getElementById("loading-progress-17").style.width= Math.round(percent * 100) +'%';
        }
    });
    request.upload.addEventListener('load', function(event){
        document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'none';
    });
    request.upload.addEventListener('error', function(event){
        alert('Upload failed');
    });
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event){
        if (this.readyState == 4){
            if(this.status == 200){
                var links = document.getElementById('uploaded');
                var uploaded = eval(this.response);
                var div, a;
                for (var i = 0; i < uploaded.length; ++i){
                    div = document.createElement('div');
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.setAttribute('href', 'files/' + uploaded[i]);
                    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uploaded[i]));
                    div.appendChild(a);
                    links.appendChild(div);
                }
            }else{
                console.log('server replied with HTTP status ' + this.status);
            }
        }
    });
    request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'block';
    request.send(data);

}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event){

    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', handleUpload);
});
```

The form of sending is already set but can't really modify it well because didn't work with javascript much. All i try to do is to pass `var folder = 7;` to upload.php as seen in this part of code :

```
request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'block';
request.send(data);
```

Any idea how to pass the variable?

Comment: `eval(this.response);` are you kidding me? What about the tried 'n tested `JSON.parse`? also `request.open` expects 3 params: third is a bool to indecate the request should be (a)sync: `true` is what you want it to be

Comment: about first 2 questions can't really understand you . And about `request.open` i know it take 3 parameters but found the code like that and it's working i think it's set to true as default

Comment: The first 2 questions are the same thing: you don't _eval_ JSON encoded data, you parse it using `JSON.parse`, besides: `eval('{foo:"bar"}')` won't work: eval needs parentheses: `eval('('+this.responseText+')')`, but eval is _evil_. [Read the docs on `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem JSON.parse should be used where available here (IE8+), but eval is not evil in this case at all.  You should read up more on eval, starting with http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/.

Comment: @RayNicholus: `eval` is definitly _evil_ in this case. It's a piece of cake to intercept the response and inject mallicious JS code in this script. For browsers that don't offer the JSON object natively, [there are safer ways](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) than using `eval` XSS attacks are too easy when using `eval` on ajax responses, especially when not even testing if the string contains the `function` keyword! Granted: `eval` has its place, but _never trust the network_ is worth keeping in mind. The network is not a trusted source, so don't go `eval`-ing whatever it sends

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm sorry, but this is not a case where eval is plainly unreasonable.  No client-side code is safe from attacks, so you could classify eval as evil in all cases using your logic.  It's perfectly reasonable to eval a response from a trusted server if `JSON.parse` is not available.  And the origin of the "eval is evil" mantra has nothing to do with to the security (or insecurity) of eval.  I encourage you to read the article I cited.  It includes some explanations from Douglas Crockford and Nicholas Zakas, two authorities on the subject.

Comment: @RayNicholus: I _have_ read it, and it _does_ state that `eval`-ing the response opens you up to man-in-the-middle attacks, just as it does to [script injection attacks](http://indixperts.blogspot.be/2011/12/ajax-injection-attack-new-way-to-hack.html). Basically, `eval` + ajax isn't the only security issue, but using `json2.js` for older browsers takes away one vulnerability, using `eval` here, simply _because there are other vulnerabilities_ is pure stupidity. I can't be kind about this. `eval`, as used here, has been proven to be a vulnerability, and there are safe(r) alternatives. Use them

Comment: Besides: the link doesn't advocate the use of `eval`, it acknowledges the risks, but merely tries to convay that `eval` _can_ be used safely, if you know what you're doing. This is _not an example of safe use_. I can visit this page, intercept the response, and inject my own snippet of code. That's just a _fact_, using JSON.parse (either native object or through json2.js) _fixes this_. This isn't rocket science

Comment: First i am glad that the question opened the great discussion

Comment: @Roy Nicholus you are the developer of fine uploader!! that's great :) you didn't face any problem like mine ? this code is a file uploader with progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code may be

```
data.append('folder', folder);
request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'block';
request.send(data);
```

your variable in php will be

```
$_REQUEST['folder']
```

Comment: $_REQUEST not $_POST?

Comment: $_REQUEST includes $_POST & $_GET & $_COOKIE